# Logic design k-map question

Tags: karnaugh-map

[image: K-map, d's represent don't care terms]

Hi everyone I'm trying to minimize this boolean function F(A, B, C, D) = ∑m(7, 8, 9, 12, 13)
don't care terms(2, 3, 6, 10, 11, 14). My main question is about the row of don't care terms in the bottom row, do I include this as a group of 4 when minimizing? I assumed I should and got this product-of-sums AB'C + AC' + ACD' + A'C + B'C. I'm also, not that great at simplifying so do AC' and A'C cancell to get AB'C + ACD' + B'C? Any and all help is appreciated especially if you could give an explanation on how you simplified, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of minimizing a boolean function is that you want to output the same `0`s and `1`s with the smallest number of terms. A `don't care` can be either a `0` or a `1` - whichever makes the function simpler.

In your case, there's no reason to treat the entire `CD'` block of `don't care`s as `1`s: if it doesn't make your SOP function simpler, don't add it.

I think the simplest SOP expression is `AC' + A'C`. Here's a picture of those two terms.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer that makes sense to me and the explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `don't care`s are grouped with `1`s (or `0`s) if it can simplify the logic.

Since the bottom row has only `don't care`s there is no need to include the bottom row. You will get the answer as `A'C + AC'`. But `AC'` and `A'C` does not cancel out as you said.

`A'C + AC' = A xor C`